# How to safely register global filters in Application_BeginRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 application that supports separate databases. The connection string for each database is resolved from the URL (domain). I also have a number of global filters that use services (EF-based classes that get data) that require a connection string. At the moment, I am passing the connection string to the service constructor.

However, since I cannot resolve the connection string in `Application_Start`, I am having to register the filters in `Application_BeginRequest`. `Request.Url` is not available before this point. Iam using the standard boilerplate code to register them:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    var userService = new UserService(Global.ConnectionString);
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute(), 1);
    filters.Add(new PermissionsFilterAttribute(userService), 2);
    filters.Add(new AppFeaturesFilterAttribute(new FeatureService(Global.ConnectionString)));
}
```

Then in `Application_BeginRequest`:

```
if(!FiltersConfigured)
{
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    FiltersConfigured = true;
}
```

`FiltersConfigured` is a Boolean property of Global.asax.cs.

I am occasionally running into an exception that stops the application dead:

```
Exception type: NullReferenceException 
Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.Mvc.FilterProviderCollection.RemoveDuplicates(List`1 filters)
```

I don't fully understand the exact cause of this particular exception, except that it is being generated by the MVC framework. I suspect that it happens because of where I am registering the global filters. The application ran fine when it was only serving one database and the connection string was picked up from the web.config by EF. At that time, the filters were registered in `Application_Start`.

Can I safely register filters in `Application_BeginRequest`? Or should I be handling connection strings in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually moved the tasks out of filters and into Child actions which get called from the layout page, and had no mysterious crashes since. So I guess the answer to my initial question is that it is not safe to register global filters in `Application_BeginRequest` in MVC 5 or earlier.